# Need confimation that the web-service does not work

Tags: android, web-services, webclient

I am learning Android OS and how to get and parse a XML file produced by a web service. I did use the http://www.webservicex.net/ for testing recently. The `GetCurrencyCode` returned the document with: country names, their country code, currency name and currency code.

When writing the Xml.newPullParser() (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html), I was not able to make it working -- observing errors that I was not used to.

After that I have checked the service server again and it seems it does not work now. Please, can you confirm that the http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx/GetCurrencyCode returns a visual text (in a browser):

```
System.IO.IOException: There is not enough space on the disk.

   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.WriteCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.FileStream.FlushWrite(Boolean calledFromFinalizer)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.Stream.Close()
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.TextWriter.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)
   at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.Compiler.Compile(Assembly parent, String ns, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters xmlParameters, Evidence evidence)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters parameters, Assembly assembly, Hashtable assemblies)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly..ctor(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, String location, Evidence evidence)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.FromMappings(XmlMapping[] mappings, Type type)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.XmlReturn.GetInitializers(LogicalMethodInfo[] methodInfos)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.XmlReturnWriter.GetInitializers(LogicalMethodInfo[] methodInfos)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.MimeFormatter.GetInitializers(Type type, LogicalMethodInfo[] methodInfos)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerType..ctor(Type type)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.Initialize()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)
```

This should be the result of pushing the button **Invoke** in the *Test* part of the page
http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx?op=GetCurrencyCode

Can you suggest a more reliable web-service server for the purpose (i.e. learning how to download and parse a XML document)?

Comment: are you cure that you are calling the method with the expected way? You need to implement a SOAP POST, I suggest ksoap2 (android library for SOAP) -> http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/

Comment: I do not want to use SOAP. But this is unrelated. I do observe the error text in my usual web browser. I am almost sure it was not there earlier. Can you also observe the same error text in your browser? Or, in other words, can you get anything else from the URI?

Comment: I see the same error in the browser but as far as I know when you are trying to "talk" to a SOAP server you have to send a SOAP request (so opening url in browser is of no use). Open http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx you see the description methods and also the Service Description url which leads to a WSDL (xml format) description file of the SOAP web-service.

Comment: Thanks (+1). But you can see that http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx?op=GetCurrencyCode suggests to press Invoke button to use the HTTP POST for testing of the operation. It should return a XML content. This is enough for me. It worked say a week ago. I only wanted to be sure it can be seen the same way from elsewhere. Anyway, I do not want to use SOAP, and I do not need it for the purpose.